# Generate a large data table in SQL from an exsiting table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, pivot

I would be grateful for your help. I have a table like this (Sample of the date):

```
Amount  Desc    Month   SM  code    ID
$32,323.00  Bla1    1   121 3   2424221
$4,242.00   Bla2    1   A1  3   2424221
$3,535.00   Bla3    1   A3  1   3230824
$4,984.00   Bla4    1   433 1   3230824
$47,984.00  Bla5    1   B1  1   3230824
$3,472.00   Bla6    1   D2  27  2297429
$3,239.00   Bla7    1   124 27  2297429
$4,249.00   Bla8    1   114 24  3434334
$2,492.00   Bla9    1   132 24  3434334
$424.00     Bla10   2   232 3   2424221
$24,242.00  Bla7    2   124 3   2424221
$242,424    Bla4    2   433 1   3230824
$533.00     Bla13   2   235 1   3230824
$4,342.00   Bla14   2   223 1   3230824
$24,242.00  Bla15   2   224 27  2297429
$24,242.00  Bla1    2   121 27  2297429
$4,242.00   Bla17   2   432 24  3434334
$24,224.00  Bla9    2   132 24  3434334
```

And I would like to generate a table like this:

```
SM - distinct values 
Desc
**TotalCntOfSM - number of time the SM showed up total**
**TotalCntOfSM_a (same but When code is in group (1,2,3))**  
TotalCntofSM_a1 (same but only when code is equal 1)
TotalCntofSM_a2 (same when code is equal 2)
TotalCntofSM_a3 (same but only when code is equal 3)
**TotalCntofSM_b (same but only when code is between 4-27)**
**TotalsumOfAmountForSM(Sum Total amount for the SM)**
**TotalSumOfAmountForSmOfSM_a (Sum Amount for for the SM When code is in 1,2,3)** 
TotalSumOfAmountForSmofSM_a1 (Sum Amount for the SM when code is equal 1)
TotalSumOfAmountForSmofSM_a2 (Sum Amount for the SM when code is equal 2)
TotalSumOfAmountForSmofSM_a3 (Sum Amount for the SM when code is equal 3)
**TotalSumOfAmountForSmofSM_b (Sum Amount for the SM when code is between 4-27)**


**TotalCntOfSMinJan - number of time the SM showed up total in month = 1**
**TotalCntOfSM_aIninJan (same but When code is in group (1,2,3))in month = 1**  
TotalCntofSM_a1inJan (same but only when code is equal 1) in month = 1
TotalCntofSM_a2inJan (same when code is equal 2) in month = 1
TotalCntofSM_a3inJan (same but only when code is equal 3) in month = 1
**TotalCntofSM_binJan (same but only when code is between 4-27)** in month = 1
**TotalsumOfAmountForSMinJan(Sum Total amount for the SM)** in month = 1
**TotalSumOfAmountForSmOfSM_ainJan (Sum Amount for for the SM When code is in 1,2,3)** in month = 1
TotalSumOfAmountForSmofSM_a1inJan (Sum Amount for the SM when code is equal 1) in month = 1
TotalSumOfAmountForSmofSM_a2inJan (Sum Amount for the SM when code is equal 2) in month = 1
TotalSumOfAmountForSmofSM_a3inJan (Sum Amount for the SM when code is equal 3) in month = 1
**TotalSumOfAmountForSmofSM_binJan (Sum Amount for the SM when code is between 4-27)** in month = 1
```

And same for Month = 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 etc.

Any help would be great.

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  sm,
  count(*) as TotalCntOfSM,
  sum(case when code in (1,2,3) then 1 else 0 end) as TotalCntOfSM_a ,
  sum(case when code in (1) then 1 else 0 end) as TotalCntofSM_a1 
  ---etc---
  sum(case when code in (1,2,3) then Amount else 0 end) as TotalSumOfAmountForSmOfSM_a 
  sum(case when code in (1) then Amount else 0 end) as TotalSumOfAmountForSmofSM_a1 
  ---etc---
from <table>
group by sm
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you! But How can I add the conditional Amount sum? (Not noly count).

Comment: @oco I've edit my answer to add in a bit more. Its the same theory; if the condition is met then take the value. if it is not then take 0, then sum it all up. Was that the part you were wondering about?